# How to traverse values of a generic Enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums

With this code:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(1, 2),
    B(3, 4);

    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    MyEnum(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class GetValuesFromEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {
    public void printValues() {
        // This causes "cannnot find symbol" error during compilation
        for (E value : E.values()) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetValuesFromEnum<MyEnum>().printValues();
    }
}
```

Calling `values()` on generic enum causes an error in compile time. Is it possible to somehow retrieve values of generic enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code in the following manner:

```
class GetValuesFromEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private Class<E> clazz;

    public GetValuesFromEnum(Class<E> clazz) {
        assert clazz.isEnum();
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void printValues() {
        for (E value : EnumSet.allOf(clazz)) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetValuesFromEnum<>(MyEnum.class).printValues();
    }
}
```

To be able to access enum values in runtime, you should know the class in runtime (for example, store the `Class` object in the field). Generic parameter is not enough due to erasure. Also note the usage of `EnumSet.allOf`: usually it's very cheap way of getting all the enum constants as it reuses internal enum constants array instead of copying it.

Comment: Is it possible to hide getting `class` for enum from user somehow?

Comment: @GillBates, unlikely. But probably I don't understand you. In your code it's `GetValuesFromEnum<MyEnum>()`, in my code it's `GetValuesFromEnum<>(MyEnum.class)`. Is it the big difference?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @GillBates, note that even JDK EnumSet/EnumMap must know explicitly either the enum class or at least one enum value (so enum class can be extracted from it via `.getClass()`). See, for example, [new EnumMap(Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#EnumMap%28java.util.Map%29) constructor JavaDoc: "IllegalArgumentException - if m is not an EnumMap instance and contains no mappings". It simply cannot construct from arbitrary empty map. The class is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to @Tagir Valeev's answer, another way to retrieve enum values at runtime is through `java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants()` method

```
public void printValues(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumCls) {
    for(Object obj: enumCls.getEnumConstants()) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }   
}
```